# How to return data using sqCommand.ExecuteReader();?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have Sqlite method that makes `SELECT` query:

```
try {
 myConn.Open();

 using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn)) {
  sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
  SQLiteDataReader reader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader();
  return reader.GetString(0);
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 // do exception handling
}
```

I tried to get last inserted id:

```
sql = 'SELECT id FROM Pacients ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';
```

I tried to di that like:

```
return reader.GetString(0);
```

it's throwing me down on exception "No current row"

Comment: Before trying to get anything out of a DataReader you should call Read and check the return value. If false nothing has been returned by your query. Lot of examples around.

Comment: In fact, you *must* call read to advance to the first row (and to advance to any subsequent rows)

Comment: There are a lot examples for SQL query, not for Sqlitre. Can you help with that?

Comment: I have found this ` while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
        }`. I have only one column, value in result, how to get this?

Comment: The example for SQL are absolutely good also for SQLite. You just need to use the SQLite classes instead of the SqlServer ones. Both are implementations of the base class [DbDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling ExecuteReader you need to call Read to position on the first record of the dataset. Read returns true/false to inform you if there are records to read. So your code changes to

```
try {
 myConn.Open();

 using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn)) {
  sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
  SQLiteDataReader reader = sqCommand.ExecuteReader();
  if(reader.Read())
     return reader.GetString(0);
  else
     return ""; // or whatever you want to return if no records are present
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 // do exception handling
}
```

Said that, remember that if you want to retrieve just one column from a single row like you have in your query then it is better to use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader

```
try {
 myConn.Open();

 using(SQLiteCommand sqCommand = new SQLiteCommand(sql, myConn)) {
  sqCommand.CommandText = sql;
  object result = sqCommand.ExecuteScalar();
  return result != null ? result.ToString() : "";
 }
} catch (Exception e) {
 // do exception handling
}
```

Comment: Thak you, hw to return all data here: `if(reader.Read())
     return reader.GetString(0);`? That after get value by column name?

Comment: Your example returns zero or 1 record. What do you mean with _all data_?

Comment: İ mean case when I select some columns by condition like: `select column1, column2, column3 WHERE....` Then I need to get it like res['column1'], etc

Comment: In that case you should have a class that represent your data. Create an instance of that class, fill its properties reading the various reader["colname"] and then return the instance of the class. If you have many records returned by the query, you use the example with the while loop and build a List of your class and return the list

Comment: I want to use this code for SELECT and UPDATE queries

Comment: Update queries are executed with ExecuteNonQuery. so the DataReader doesn't really apply.

Comment: I can not fill data, because SQL can be different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158769/discussion-between-steve-and-opv).